# pass run configuration arguments from docker run command

Tags: docker

I should use docker for linux application
now we run the application with run configuration arguments
the run command is APP_NAME -ARG VALUE
how do I pass those args by using docker run command?
Thanks

Comment: Have you read official docs about docker run?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to docker as env variable `-e VARNAME=VALUE`

Please [Docker Official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/reference/run/) - SECTION - `ENV (environment variables)`